# Whatever happened with InstantLive technology?

Tags: cd, live-music

Some 10 years ago, Clear Channel attempted to grab an even larger market share by offering [InstantLive CDs](http://www.techhive.com/article/122720/article.html).  However, I've never seen or heard of one at any show I've ever been to.

Did this technology ever take off?  Has anyone here ever bought one and can comment on what the packaging was/is like?

Answer (score 3):

The technology was there in 2003, and it had several big bands attached to it, but artists encountered issues with it; the deal necessary to get Instant Live CDs was too restrictive and it eventually fell out of use.  The last reference to Clear Channel's version of it I could find was in a 2004 Rolling Stone article.

That said, the InstantLive technology lived on. Even at the time, there were smaller companies (such as Live Nation) offering the service. On the other hand, the current trend toward digital sales of music has likely made a paid, contracted service unnecessary.

Comment: I've also never seen it in use, though the packaging appears to be very simple; the services which sell them online, like http://instantlive.shop.musictoday.com/ , show a simple recolor of the band's logo with the concert's name.